# how to stop loop on this slider

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I'm using this slider to my site. everything is going fine. It automatically plays slide from first to last and after completeing the first cycle it comes to first slide again. I want to stop the slide cycle.
I want to stop auto loop on this slider.
please help me.
I've attachted my js code.
http://codyhouse.co/gem/hero-slider/

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var slidesWrapper = $('.cd-hero-slider');
if ( slidesWrapper.length > 0 ) {
    var primaryNav = $('.cd-primary-nav'),
        sliderNav = $('.cd-slider-nav'),
        navigationMarker = $('.cd-marker'),
        slidesNumber = slidesWrapper.children('li').length,
        visibleSlidePosition = 0,
        autoPlayId,
        autoPlayDelay = 5000;

    uploadVideo(slidesWrapper);

    setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);

    primaryNav.on('click', function(event){
        if($(event.target).is('.cd-primary-nav')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });

    sliderNav.on('click', 'li', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedItem = $(this);
        if(!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {
            var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index(),
                activePosition = slidesWrapper.find('li.selected').index();

            if( activePosition < selectedPosition) {
                nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
            } else {
                prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
            }

            visibleSlidePosition = selectedPosition;

            updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, selectedPosition);
            updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, selectedPosition+1);
            setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);
        }
    });
}

function nextSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
}

function prevSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
}

function updateSliderNavigation(pagination, n) {
    var navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');
    navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
    pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');
}

function setAutoplay(wrapper, length, delay) {
    if(wrapper.hasClass('autoplay')) {
        clearInterval(autoPlayId);
        autoPlayId = window.setInterval(function(){autoplaySlider(length)}, delay);
    }
}

function autoplaySlider(length) {
    if( visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
        nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
        visibleSlidePosition +=1;
    } else {
        prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
        visibleSlidePosition = 0;
    }
    updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, visibleSlidePosition+1);
    updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
}

function uploadVideo(container) {
    container.find('.cd-bg-video-wrapper').each(function(){
        var videoWrapper = $(this);
        if( videoWrapper.is(':visible') ) {
            var videoUrl = videoWrapper.data('video'),
                video = $('<video loop><source src="'+videoUrl+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+videoUrl+'.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>');
            video.appendTo(videoWrapper);
            if(videoWrapper.parent('.cd-bg-video.selected').length > 0) video.get(0).play();
        }
    });
}

function checkVideo(hiddenSlide, container, n) {
    var hiddenVideo = hiddenSlide.find('video');
    if( hiddenVideo.length > 0 ) hiddenVideo.get(0).pause();

    var visibleVideo = container.children('li').eq(n).find('video');
    if( visibleVideo.length > 0 ) visibleVideo.get(0).play();
}

function updateNavigationMarker(marker, n) {
    marker.removeClassPrefix('item').addClass('item-'+n);
}

$.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
    this.each(function(i, el) {
        var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
            return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
        });
        el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
    });
    return this;
};
```

});

```
<section class="cd-hero">
    <ul class="cd-hero-slider autoplay">
        <!-- <li class="selected">
            <div class="cd-full-width">
                <h2>SLider Title 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <a href="#" class="cd-btn">Article &amp; Download</a>
            </div>
        </li> -->

        <li class="selected">
            <div class="cd-half-width">
                <!-- <h2>Slide title here</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In consequatur cumque natus!</p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">Start</a>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn secondary">Learn More</a> -->
                <img src="img/slider-logo-1.png" alt="">
                <img src="img/slider-logo-2.png" alt="">
                <img src="img/slider-logo-3.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
                <img src="img/led.jpg" alt="tech 1">
            </div> 
        </li>

        <!-- <li>
            <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
                <img src="assets/tech-2.jpg" alt="tech 2">
            </div> 

            <div class="cd-half-width">
                <h2>Slide title here</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In consequatur cumque natus!</p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">Start</a>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn secondary">Learn More</a>
            </div> 

        </li> -->

        <li class="cd-bg-video">
            <div class="cd-full-width">
                <h2>Slide title here</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, explicabo.</p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">Learn more</a>
            </div> <!-- .cd-full-width -->

            <div class="cd-bg-video-wrapper" data-video="assets/video/video">
                <!-- video element will be loaded using jQuery -->
            </div> <!-- .cd-bg-video-wrapper -->
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="cd-full-width">
                <h2>wow</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, explicabo.</p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">Start</a>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn secondary">Learn More</a>
            </div> <!-- .cd-full-width -->
        </li>
    </ul> <!-- .cd-hero-slider -->

    <div class="cd-slider-nav">
        <nav>
            <span class="cd-marker item-1"></span>

            <ul>
                <li class="selected"><a href="#0">Intro</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#0">Tech 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Tech 2</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="#0">Video</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
    </div> <!-- .cd-slider-nav -->
</section>
```

Comment: when you want to stop?

Comment: Please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: At the bottom of the page, before the change log block, it say *"Note: if you want to animate the slider automatically, add the .autoplay class to the ul.cd-hero-slider element."* So I guess you need to remove the class.

Comment: when the 3rd slider is active it will not slide to 1st one again.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question instead of simply giving us a link. Please see the link @MattO'Brien posted for more information on how to write a high quality question.

Comment: I see the note. It's for auto play. that means it will slide 1st to 2nd and so on automatically. My concern is when third slide is complete it should not come to 1st again. @Karl-AndréGagnon

Comment: here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qaq4os4v @Karl-AndréGagnon

Comment: Without modifying the core of the plugin, your request is not possible.

Comment: so how can I do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qaq4os4v/1/

Comment: It works. If I click on intro or video it should start auto playing again. and the last slide need to stop sliding like as your fiddle. @Karl-AndréGagnon

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qaq4os4v/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


var slidesWrapper = $('.cd-hero-slider');
if ( slidesWrapper.length > 0 ) {
    var primaryNav = $('.cd-primary-nav'),
        sliderNav = $('.cd-slider-nav'),
        navigationMarker = $('.cd-marker'),
        slidesNumber = slidesWrapper.children('li').length,
        visibleSlidePosition = 0,
        autoPlayId,
        autoPlayDelay = 5000;

    slidesWrapper.find('li').on('webkitTransitionEnd.a otransitionend.a oTransitionEnd.a msTransitionEnd.a transitionend.a', function(){
        if($(this).is(':last-child') && $(this).is('.selected')){
            slidesWrapper.removeClass('autoplay');
        }
    });

    sliderNav.find('li:first-child').on('click', function(){
        slidesWrapper.addClass('autoplay');
        setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);
    });

    uploadVideo(slidesWrapper);

    setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);

    primaryNav.on('click', function(event){
        if($(event.target).is('.cd-primary-nav')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });

    sliderNav.on('click', 'li', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedItem = $(this);
        if(!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {
            var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index(),
                activePosition = slidesWrapper.find('li.selected').index();

            if( activePosition < selectedPosition) {
                nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
            } else {
                prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
            }

            visibleSlidePosition = selectedPosition;

            updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, selectedPosition);
            updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, selectedPosition+1);
            setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);
        }
    });
}

function nextSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
}

function prevSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
}

function updateSliderNavigation(pagination, n) {
    var navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');
    navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
    pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');
}

function setAutoplay(wrapper, length, delay) {
    if(wrapper.hasClass('autoplay')) {
        clearInterval(autoPlayId);
        autoPlayId = window.setInterval(function(){autoplaySlider(length)}, delay);
    }
}

function autoplaySlider(length) {
    if(!slidesWrapper.hasClass('autoplay')){
        return clearInterval(autoPlayId);
    }
    if( visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
        nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
        visibleSlidePosition +=1;
    } else {
        prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
        visibleSlidePosition = 0;
    }
    updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, visibleSlidePosition+1);
    updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
}

function uploadVideo(container) {
    container.find('.cd-bg-video-wrapper').each(function(){
        var videoWrapper = $(this);
        if( videoWrapper.is(':visible') ) {
            var videoUrl = videoWrapper.data('video'),
                video = $('<video loop><source src="'+videoUrl+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+videoUrl+'.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>');
            video.appendTo(videoWrapper);
            if(videoWrapper.parent('.cd-bg-video.selected').length > 0) video.get(0).play();
        }
    });
}

function checkVideo(hiddenSlide, container, n) {
    var hiddenVideo = hiddenSlide.find('video');
    if( hiddenVideo.length > 0 ) hiddenVideo.get(0).pause();

    var visibleVideo = container.children('li').eq(n).find('video');
    if( visibleVideo.length > 0 ) visibleVideo.get(0).play();
}

function updateNavigationMarker(marker, n) {
    marker.removeClassPrefix('item').addClass('item-'+n);
}

$.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
    this.each(function(i, el) {
        var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
            return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
        });
        el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
    });
    return this;
};
```

});